# Three.js raycasting always returning empty array

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I have many objects in my scene but the intersects variable always returns an empty array, any ideas?

```
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); //new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, mouse);
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera); 
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
```

Comment: is this code executed in the render function? does your `mouse` variable have valid coords?

Comment: Mouse has valid co ordinates (-1 to 1 on both X and y) but the function isn't under the render function, should it be??

Comment: it should in `onMouseMove` http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster

Comment: What about onMouseDown??

Comment: Get it working for onMouseMove and then you can add onMouseDown.

Comment: Got it working! Turns out it was an issue in the version of three.js I was using :') Updating three.js without modifying my code resolved the issue. Thanks for all the help!